# trying to use redis plugin for play framework v2

Tags: redis, playframework-2.2

I tried using the redis plugin from the following source with play framework v2.2.1 and received the error message copied below - any thoughts on troubleshooting this will be greatly appreciated.

**Source**:

```
https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis
```

**Error**:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.1.0;2.0.4: not found
```

I added the following to build.sbt:

**build.sbt:**

```
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.0.4",
```

I also added the play.plugins file in the conf directory with the following:

```
550:com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using version 2.1.1 and it is working:

"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.1.1",

Comment: for some reason, I can't seem to import the following in my java class: import com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin;
import redis.clients.jedis.*;  Any thoughts - thanks

Comment: execute commands "play clean compile" then "play idea" and try again.

Comment: I'm using play eclipse (using eclipse) - not working for some reason  - thank you for your help (yes, I did use play clean compile as well)

Comment: do you mind sharing the relevant portions of your build.sbt & play.plugins file for this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem with `play 2.5`. But I solve the problem by add resolvers and dependencies in `sbt.build`

```
resolvers += "sedis-fix" at "https://dl.bintray.com/graingert/maven/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.5.0"
```